# External http link not recognized as link

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have the following document:

```
* Test
| Links |
|-------|
| [[http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask]] |
```

This Link is not recognized as a Link. If I press TAB while the cursor is on the link the cursor moves to the beginning of the line and I get a warning in messages:

> font-lock-fontify-keywords-region: Wrong type argument: listp, org-table

If I remove http from the link, it works. If I change http to some other term like httpd it works also. It just seems, http and https do not work.

What am I doing wrong? What is missing? How can I add a external http link to an org table?

Comment: This seems to be a bug fixed (two days ago) by [`9eface25da489cbb7b8c2f4951850b571f74f660`](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=9eface25da489cbb7b8c2f4951850b571f74f660).

Comment: See also: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/104444

Comment: An update: Org 8.2.10 (shipped with Emacs 24.5.1) recognizes the link correctly. (And I can still reproduce this bug using Org 8.3.3.)

Comment: @Constantine I'm having this problem as well. Could you explain how to use the link to fix the bug?

Comment: The fix has made its way into recent releases -- I was hitting the same version, but using org-plus-contrib-20160201 fixed it for me. I'm guessing that version or any later would do.