# Org broke! How do I downgrade?

Tags: org-mode, package

I started having some problems with org mode after upgrading my melpa packages. One of the problems is described in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19874/external-http-link-not-recognized-as-link).

I'd like to simply downgrade to my previous version of org-mode until these issues are resolved. Is there a way to do this?

For the record, issuing `M-x org-version` returns

```
Org-mode version 8.3.3 (8.3.3-26-ge92a06-elpaplus @ ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20160125/)
```

Also, I'm using Emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the package from ELPA and using the one bundled with Emacs? That's one way to downgrade.

Comment: Would I do this by simply deleting the directory `~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20160125`?

Comment: I would do `M-x package-list-packages`, mark Org by pressing `d`, then press `x` to "execute".

Comment: According to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Files.html#Package-Files) *Deleting a package (see Package Menu) involves deleting the corresponding package subdirectory*, so seems like deleting a directory should work too.